# Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder

Tags: php, laravel, model

I have 2 model one is task and another is order. I have used here one to many relation. Here is my code

```
    public function orders(){
    return $this->hasMany(Order::where('service_id', null), 'offerid');
}
```

for task

```
    public function task()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Task::class, 'id');
}
```

I have to fetch only those table who have service_id null. when i make like this then showing error Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.

```
$tasks = Task::where('sub_category', $id)->with('serimages', 'serSignleImg', 'user', 'orders')->get();
```

This is the query where i fetching all data. I have pass them through api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have error in your relation method

```
  public function orders(){
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class, 'offerid')->whereNull('offerid');
}
```

or you can do like this

```
   public function orders(){
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class, 'offerid');
    }

$tasks = Task::where(['sub_category', $id)->with('serimages', 'serSignleImg', 'user', 'orders'=>function($query){$query->whereNull('offerid')}])->get();
```

Comment: yes, but how can i fetch those data where is service_id null ?

Comment: show you relation table migration both Task and order

Comment: offerid and serviceid both are different filed. I have to only fetch here where is service id null

Comment: then add whereNull('serviceid ')

Comment: @MDMasum.updaed answet

Comment: let me try. will back to you

Comment: sure @john lobo. Not able to do before time. it's take 5 minute